# Understanding React basic example

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the [basic example on the React frontpage](https://facebook.github.io/react/) there is:

```
class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="Jane" />, mountNode);
```

If I do something similar in my setup I get:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected } (54:11)

  52 | 
  53 | class EisTable extends React.Component {
> 54 |   render() {
     |            ^
  55 |     return <div>Hello </div>;
  56 |   }
  57 | }
```

Which yes does make sens to me. Probably it is some ES6 trickery I don't know, but for convenient JS this syntax does not make sense. What is this `render(){}` called and what do I need to make it work?

Comment: This is called Shorthand methods

Answer (score 2):

As you guessed, that's a syntax introduced in ES6 (aka ES2015), called [shorthand methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions).

This

```
{
  render() {}
}
```

is a shorthand syntax for this

```
{
  render: function() {}
}
```

You can either write it the long way (for compatibility with older JS specs) or use a more recent JS engine. Here's a compatibility table for this specific language feature: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions_shorthand_methods

If you're using babel, make sure to include the `es2015` preset.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need to configure the ability to transpile ES6 in your environment.

To do that for react, they recommend babel and webpack.

`render()` function is part of the lifecycle in a react component, it expect to be returned shadowDOM when in web.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

Comment: I have babel working otherwise I could not have `class` right?